# Не отрабатывает url в js скрипте

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mvc

Есть скрипт, который вызывается при нажатии кнопки в форме:

```
function logonUser() {
    //var postData = getData('#registerBox');
    var login = $('#username').val();
    var pwd = $('#password').val();
    var postData = "username="+login+"&password="+pwd;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        //async: false,
        url: "/user/logonUser/", //TODO: url до action регистрацииюзера
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data['success']) {
                alert('Регистрация успешна'); //TODO: заменить на что-то более симпатичное
                //Тут скрываем форму и показываем инфо о юзере
            }
            else {
                alert(data['message']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

По непонятной причине не передается параметр `url: "/user/logonUser/"` в мой `userController.php`, который должен получить массив `$_POST`

Смотрю в  firebug - Сеть: должно быть `http://localhost/user/logonuser/`, а там просто `http://localhost.`
PS. роутинг работает нормально. `.htaccess` настроен

Comment: При вызове http://localhost/user/logonuser/ из браузера или curl php скипт отрабатывает нормально

Comment: попробуйте так url: "user/logonUser/"

Comment: @GhostDogg через curl php Вы обращаетесь к "logonuser" с маленькой буквы, а в коде из вопроса к "logonUser"

Comment: я уже в контроллере action сменил на logon. Решение ниже описал )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$.post("/test.php", { url: "/user/logonUser/", ... },
        function(data){
            if (data != 'error') {
            res = JSON.parse(data);
            }
});
```

Comment: Это вместо моего тела функции?

Answer (score 1):

Вся эта конструкция заработала, когда я свою функцию вынес за пределы

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... }
```

Спасибо всем за помощь!